# Handling error events in Yeoman custom generator when trying to run a command

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to start a git repo when scaffolding an application with a yeoman custom generator, this is what I got at the `install` step:

```
  install: function () {
    this.installDependencies();
    this.spawnCommand('npm', ['i', '--save' , 'express', 'mongodb', 'mongoose', 'lodash', 'bluebird', 'async', 'morgan']);
    this.spawnCommand('git' ['init']); // Here fails
    this.spawnCommand('git', ['add', '.']);
    this.spawnCommand('git', ['commit', '-am', '"yo scaffolded app"']);
  }
```

However when trying to run this I get:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
TypeError: Bad argument
    at TypeError (native)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1136:26)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
    at spawn (/storage/home/dev/generator-koala/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:87:19)
    at spawnCommand (/storage/home/dev/generator-koala/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/spawn_command.js:17:10)
    at module.exports.yeoman.generators.Base.extend.install (/storage/home/dev/generator-koala/generators/app/index.js:72:10)
    at /storage/home/dev/generator-koala/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:421:16
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
```

I do have git installed, how should I fix this?

Comment: Try only running `git init` to reduce the scope.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: You have a lot of commands being triggered at the same time, so if you only run one, you'll make sure nothing is failing due to a side effect. You need to reduce the scope of your issue to be able to correctly debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use callback, so change `spawnCommand`  to `spawnCommandSync`

```
install: function () {
    this.installDependencies();
    this.spawnCommandSync('npm', ['i', '--save' , 'express', 'mongodb', 'mongoose', 'lodash', 'bluebird', 'async', 'morgan']);
    this.spawnCommandSync('git' ['init']);
    this.spawnCommandSync('git', ['add', '.']);
    this.spawnCommandSync('git', ['commit', '-am', '"yo scaffolded app"']);
  }
```